# How can the scheduler of Task.Run be changed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, task

I need to run a few tasks that require to be ran using a specific scheduler as they would fail otherwise since the objects they do instantiate can only be from a specific thread.

Using `Task.Factory.StartNew` works well, the only thing is that the syntax is a bit cumbersome.

So I came up with the idea of writing an extension method that could allow me to keep the terse syntax of `Task.Run` but specify another scheduler than `TaskScheduler.Default`. I am having a hard time figuring out how to write such extension method, however.

**Question:**

How can I change the scheduler of `Task.Run` it is meant to run with, if possible at all?

**Code example:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private async void Test()
    {
        // game objects can only be created from Unity main thread, get its scheduler

        var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

        // 1. syntax using factory, works but is a bit cumbersome

        await Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => new GameObject("test"),
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            scheduler
        );

        // 2. ideal syntax though it will fail since it'll run with the wrong scheduler

        await Task.Run(() => new GameObject("test"));

        // 3. ideal syntax but how to implement .Schedule method?

        await Task.Run(() => new GameObject("test")).Schedule(scheduler);
    }
}
```

**Extension method:**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Task<T> Schedule<T>(this Task<T> task, TaskScheduler scheduler)
    {
        // how, if possible at all to write this method?

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: there's no need to use `StartNew` to run a task using the current sync context.  If you want to run code using the current sync context just *run the code*, no need for another task.  In this case your code is *already* on the main thread, else the current context's scheduler wouldn't give it to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [`TaskFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory). Just create one with your desired `TaskScheduler`. Also, you generally do not want to use the default options settings. Assuming you're using the tasks with `await`, you generally want at least `DenyChildAttach`:

```
var factory = new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
    TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
    scheduler);
```

Once created (one time), you can use `factory.StartNew` to queue work without having to pass all the parameters every time.

Comment: Couldn't expect better, an answer from the Guru of async, thanks :)

Comment: How about skip the `TaskFactory` and just write this: `Task.CompletedTask.ContinueWith( t => DoWork(), scheduler )`?

Comment: @HappyNomad: The point of `TaskFactory` is that you don't have to repeat all the parameters each time you want to start a task.

Comment: @StephenCleary The original question asks for `Task.Run` behavior except with a different `scheduler`. I think that `Task.CompletedTask.ContinueWith` is a better choice since not even once do you have to supply those parameters that you're uninterested in thinking about or changing.

Comment: @StephenCleary I just noticed that `ContinueWith` defaults to `TaskContinuationOptions.None`. I guess you'd recommend against this default `ContinueWIth` behavior? That'd leave `TaskFactory` as the best option after all.

Comment: @StephenCleary Practically speaking, does `DenyChildAttach` matter? A child task would have to be _intentionally_ attached, which I doubt happens. I ask because a quick search reveals that those who instantiate a `TaskFactory` in their view models (for the purpose of posting to the UI thread as I am) are using its single-arg constructor that accepts only the scheduler and leaves the default options.

Comment: @HappyNomad: What I'm saying is that once you have a `TaskFactory`, you can call `StartNew` and not have to pass a scheduler or anything else (except the delegate, of course). If you do `ContinueWith`, you'd have to pass the scheduler each time along with the delegate. Also, it just looks weird, and I dislike adding time-to-comprehension just to be clever. Re `DenyChildAttach`, I generally recommend it (defensive programming) but I wouldn't say it's strictly necessary.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks for clarifying. Finally, what's `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` for here? Doesn't that just emulate `ConfigureAwait( false )`? Or is it more generally useful?

Comment: @HappyNomad: `ExecuteSynchronously` is emulating the `await` behavior. Since there is a scheduler being passed, it *probably* will have no effect but that actually depends on the scheduler. It inlines continuations when possible and if the scheduler agrees to.

Comment: @StephenCleary So an `ExecuteSynchronously` option provided to the `TaskFactory` constructor could affect where the code inside a delegate passed to `TaskFactory.StartNew` will run? Does that include if the `StartNew` call is `await`ed?

Comment: @HappyNomad: `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` only modifies the behavior of `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAll` / `TaskFactory.ContinueWhenAny`, not `StartNew`.

Comment: @StephenCleary I see now, thanks. I don't use those methods. But if I do then omitting `ExecuteSynchronously` may still make sense since switching contexts is the intention.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't do this.  By the time you get the `Task` back from `Task.Run` the task is already scheduled on the default scheduler, and may already be running.  If you want to use a custom scheduler, don't use `Task.Run`.  Either use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, or write your own method to schedule a new task in a particular manner.